# Combine dataframes to allocate lenders to borrowers, in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: lenders and borrowers. I want to combine values from lenders to borrowers, as below.

```
LenderDF = pd.DataFrame({
'LenderID':['Lender 1', 'Lender 2','Lender 3','Lender 4', 'Lender 5'],
'AmountHave': [300, 150, 500, 100, 200]
})
borrowerDF = pd.DataFrame({
'borrowerID': ['Borrower 1', 'Borrower 2','Borrower 3','Borrower 4'],
'AmountNeed': [100,200,150,300]
 })

print(LenderDF)
print(borrowerDF)

   LenderID  AmountHave
0  Lender 1         300
1  Lender 2         150
2  Lender 3         500
3  Lender 4         100
4  Lender 5         200

   borrowerID  AmountNeed
0  Borrower 1         100
1  Borrower 2         200
2  Borrower 3         150
3  Borrower 4         300
```

The final output I'm trying to get is:

```
   BorrowerID  AmountNeeded  LenderID  LenderHave(after lending amount)  RemainingAmount
0  Borrower 1           100  Lender 1                                     300              200
1  Borrower 2           200  Lender 1                                     200                0
2  Borrower 3           150  Lender 2                                     150                0
3  Borrower 4           300  Lender 3                                     500              200
```

Example:

- First lender has 300 so they can lend money to (say) Borrower 1 and Borrower 2:
- **300**(*firstLender*) >= **100** (*firstBorrower Amount needed*)
- So assign or set value of First lender "Lender 1" to the Borrower who
  took the money and set the remaining value **200** First value of
  AmountLenderHave will be 300 since this is the first time that person
  is lending amount.
- 200(firstLender) >= 200 (secondBorrower amount needed)

Likeise, iterate on each lender row and so on, until no lender is remaining.

Comment: I don't see that formulating it as dataframes helps; usually you'd formulate this as recursion (maybe with backtracking, or a little randomness). Essentially you have one list of `lenders = [300,150,500,100,200]` and a different list `borrowers = [100,200,150,300]`. And you want to come up with an association between them that is good, if not optimal. The names/ ids are just clutter, we don't need them, integers work just as well. So you'd just have recursive function calls with the two lists of "remaining lenders" and "remaining borrowers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to do this using pandas join functions, it's really a problem where you should iterate over a list of borrowers. The below does what you are after:

```py
import pandas as pd

LenderDF = pd.DataFrame({
'LenderID':['Lender 1', 'Lender 2','Lender 3','Lender 4', 'Lender 5'],
'AmountHave': [300, 150, 500, 100, 200]
})
borrowerDF = pd.DataFrame({
'borrowerID': ['Borrower 1', 'Borrower 2','Borrower 3','Borrower 4'],
'AmountNeed': [100,200,150,300]
 })

lenders = LenderDF.to_dict(orient='records')
borrowers = borrowerDF.to_dict(orient='records')

for borrower in borrowers:
    # get next lender who can pay
    amount_needed = borrower['AmountNeed']
    lender = next(lender for lender in lenders if lender['AmountHave'] >= amount_needed)
    borrower['LenderID'] = lender['LenderID']
    borrower['LenderHave'] = lender['AmountHave']
    borrower['LenderRemaining'] = lender['AmountHave'] - amount_needed
    # Update lenders amount
    lender['AmountHave'] -= amount_needed


print(pd.DataFrame(borrowers))

   borrowerID  AmountNeed  LenderID  LenderHave  LenderRemaining
0  Borrower 1         100  Lender 1         300              200
1  Borrower 2         200  Lender 1         200                0
2  Borrower 3         150  Lender 2         150                0
3  Borrower 4         300  Lender 3         500              200
```

Comment: In case when All lenders have finished and there are borrowers are still present, We want to leave the records for those borrowers field LenderID, LenderHave, LenderRemaining as empty.

Comment: Is there a way that we can leave the LenderID, LenderHave, LenderRemaining as empty, when there is no lender. Because I get


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 32, in <module>
    lender = next(lender for lender in lenders if lender['AmountHave'] >= amount_needed)
StopIteration

Comment: I was able to add if condition and "break" when its empty. Thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The other option would be to catch the `StopIteration` with a `try: ... except StopIteration` block for when there is no lender with enough money for the borrower

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.  I too convert the dataframe to lists.  This code also takes care of the situation where a borrower has to borrow from multiple lenders, as in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
lenderDF = pd.DataFrame({
'LenderID':['Lender 1', 'Lender 2','Lender 3','Lender 4', 'Lender 5'],
'AmountHave': [300, 150, 500, 100, 200]
})
borrowerDF = pd.DataFrame({
'borrowerID': ['Borrower 1', 'Borrower 2','Borrower 3','Borrower 4'],
'AmountNeed': [100,300,150,300]
 })

lender_have = lenderDF["AmountHave"].tolist()
borrower_need = borrowerDF["AmountNeed"].tolist()

borrowerID = []
lenderID = []
borrower_remaining_need = [borrower_need[0]]
lender_before = [lender_have[0]]
lender_after = []
l = 0
b = 0
while b < len(borrower_need):
    borrowerID.append(f'Borrower {b + 1}')
    lenderID.append(f'Lender {l + 1}')
    remaining_funds = lender_before[-1] - borrower_remaining_need[-1]

    if remaining_funds > 0:
        lender_after.append(remaining_funds)
        lender_before.append(remaining_funds)
        b += 1
        if b< len(borrower_need):
            borrower_remaining_need.append(borrower_need[b])

    elif remaining_funds < 0:
        lender_after.append(0)
        borrower_remaining_need.append(borrower_remaining_need[-1] - lender_before[-1])
        if l+1 < len(lender_have):
            lender_before.append(lender_have[l+1])
        l += 1

    elif remaining_funds == 0:
        lender_after.append(0)
        if l+1 < len(lender_have):
            lender_before.append(lender_have[l+1])
        if b+1 < len(borrower_need):
            borrower_remaining_need.append(borrower_need[b+1])
        b += 1
        l += 1

if len(lender_before) > len(borrowerID):
    lender_before.pop()

result_df = pd.DataFrame({"BorrowrID": borrowerID, "Amount Needed": borrower_remaining_need,
                          "LenderID": lenderID, "Lender Before": lender_before, "Lender After":lender_after},)

print(result_df)

    BorrowrID  Amount Needed  LenderID  Lender Before  Lender After
0  Borrower 1            100  Lender 1            300           200
1  Borrower 2            300  Lender 1            200             0
2  Borrower 2            100  Lender 2            150            50
3  Borrower 3            150  Lender 2             50             0
4  Borrower 3            100  Lender 3            500           400
5  Borrower 4            300  Lender 3            400           100
```